How to draft a lib not depends on a specified dependency?
I will draft a java lib built under gradle. The lib will depend some common lib like commons-lang3. To make compilation work, a specified version (suppose 1.0.1) of commons-lang3 must be provided. But the lib consumer may already import a high version commons-lang3 (suppose 1.9.11).
Finally, the application should run against commons-lang3 version 1.9.11 instead of 1.0.1. So, what should I do in my build.gradle?

When you say draft the lib, do you mean something specific, or do you just mean that you will be writing a library? Second question: When someone uses your library in an application eeding commons-lang3 in version 1.9.11, should your library still run against 1.0.1 version, or should it use the version bundled with the application?

You don't need to do anything, the Gradle configuration of the consumer has the final say.

If he still wants his version of dependency to be used shading may be necessary.

See https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/

@TheCoolDrop: For Q1, I am writing a library? For Q2, my library should run against version 1.9.11. If there is any in-compatible (for example, missing some class or some method), just break at runtime.

@MarkRotteveel I just want to know what the consumer will do. I can NOT say consumer do what it want. We are develop product for some business.

Then you should read the Gradle documentation. There are various ways that a library can constrain what the consumer resolves, but by default - IIRC - it resolves the version specified by the consumer.
